# HapiJS user session management

Tags: node.js, session, hapi.js

Below code is from HapiJS docs and it is describing how to use sessions and cookies by using *@hapi/cookie* plugin.

```
'use strict';

const Hapi = require('@hapi/hapi');


const internals = {};


// Simulate database for demo

internals.users = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'john',
        password: 'password',
    },
];


internals.renderHtml = {
    login: (message) => {

        return `
    <html><head><title>Login page</title></head><body>
    ${message ? '<h3>' + message + '</h3><br></a>' : ''}
    <form method="post" action="/login">
      Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
      Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br></a>
    <input type="submit" value="Login"></form>
    </body></html>
      `;
    },
    home: (name) => {

        return `
    <html><head><title>Login page</title></head><body>
    <h3>Welcome ${name}! You are logged in!</h3>
    <form method="get" action="/logout">
      <input type="submit" value="Logout">
    </form>
    </body></html>
      `;
    }
};


internals.server = async function () {

    const server = Hapi.server({ port: 8000 });

    await server.register(require('@hapi/cookie'));

    server.auth.strategy('session', 'cookie', {

        cookie: {
            name: 'sid-example',

            // Don't forget to change it to your own secret password!
            password: 'password-should-be-32-characters',

            // For working via HTTP in localhost
            isSecure: false
        },

        redirectTo: '/login',

        validateFunc: async (request, session) => {

            const account = internals.users.find((user) => (user.id === session.id));

            if (!account) {
                // Must return { valid: false } for invalid cookies
                return { valid: false };
            }

            return { valid: true, credentials: account };
        }
    });

    server.auth.default('session');

    server.route([
        {
            method: 'GET',
            path: '/',
            options: {
                handler: (request, h) => {

                    return internals.renderHtml.home(request.auth.credentials.name);
                }
            }
        },
        {
            method: 'GET',
            path: '/login',
            options: {
                auth: {
                    mode: 'try'
                },
                plugins: {
                    'hapi-auth-cookie': {
                        redirectTo: false
                    }
                },
                handler: async (request, h) => {

                    if (request.auth.isAuthenticated) {
                        return h.redirect('/');
                    }

                    return internals.renderHtml.login();
                }
            }
        },
        {
            method: 'POST',
            path: '/login',
            options: {
                auth: {
                    mode: 'try'
                },
                handler: async (request, h) => {

                    const { username, password } = request.payload;
                    if (!username || !password) {
                        return internals.renderHtml.login('Missing username or password');
                    }

                    // Try to find user with given credentials

                    const account = internals.users.find(
                        (user) => user.name === username && user.password === password
                    );

                    if (!account) {
                        return internals.renderHtml.login('Invalid username or password');
                    }

                    request.cookieAuth.set({ id: account.id });
                    return h.redirect('/');
                }
            }
        },
        {
            method: 'GET',
            path: '/logout',
            options: {
                handler: (request, h) => {

                    request.cookieAuth.clear();
                    return h.redirect('/');
                }
            }
        }
    ]);

    await server.start();
    console.log(`Server started at: ${server.info.uri}`);
};


internals.start = async function() {

    try {
        await internals.server();
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error(err.stack);
        process.exit(1);
    }
};

internals.start();
```

My question is: in POST login route, and after a user is successfully logged in, does `request.cookieAuth.set({ id: account.id });` save the `{id:account.id}` in memory(cache) and send it as cookie to the client? or there is nothing is saved here?.
Similarly, does `request.cookieAuth.clear();` clear the session from memory and from client ??

Answer (score 0):

Hapi.js has it's own in-memory system, but you can also choose to use something custom, like Redis or another store.

I use Hapi's store and it works fine for a single server instance.  If you plan on having a cluster of server instances, you'll need to offload storing such data to a backend store like Redis, otherwise if connections aren't sticky they will load balance with each request, and if the user hits a server instance that doesn't have the session cached, it will appear as though the user is logged out.  With a synced backend cache, all server instance share that cache data and remain in sync.

Here is how I manage things.  I would generate a unique UUID for a session key as the user id is painfully obvious.

```
export class AuthCookieData implements IAuthCookieData {
  sid: string
  constructor(data: IAuthCookieData) {
    this.sid = data.sid;
  }
}

export class AuthCookie {

  /**
   *  accepts one parameter: account
   *  account: the user account to register as {username:'username', password:'password', email: 'user@email.com'}
   *  returns: Promise with new account
   */
  static async setCookie(request: Hapi.Request, userProfile: UserProfile): Promise<void> {
      var sid = uuid.v4();
      await request.server.app['cache'].set(sid, userProfile, 0);
      request['cookieAuth'].set(new AuthCookieData({ sid: sid }));
    }
  }

  static async sessionCacheFunction(request: Hapi.Request, session: AuthCookieData) {

    var userProfile: UserProfile = await request.server.app['cache'].get(session.sid);
    if (!userProfile) {
      return { valid: false };
    } else {
      return { valid: true, credentials: userProfile };
    }

  }
}
```

```
const handler:Hapi.Lifecycle.Method = async (request: Hapi.Request, h: Hapi.ResponseToolkit) => {
  if (request.auth.isAuthenticated) {
    return request.auth.credentials;
  }
  const userProfile: UserProfile = await UserUtility.login(<ILogin>request.payload);
  if (!userProfile) {
    return Boom.badRequest('Could not authenticate.  Username or password is invalid.');
  }
  AuthCookie.setCookie(request, userProfile);
  return profile;
};
```

```
server.auth.strategy('session', 'cookie', {    
  cookie: {
    name: 'sid',
    password: Configuration.auth.password,
    isSecure: false,
    clearInvalid: true
  },
  validateFunc: AuthCookie.sessionCacheFunction
});
```